# How to optimize and automate circle detection code?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, image-processing

I have a code that can detect ellipse like structures pretty well.

Essentially given this [input image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6CQD.jpg), my output would look something like [output with segmented circles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNFMi.jpg)

but I have to manually alter 2 parameters (C value of adaptive threshold and morphology close value) depending on how bright the image is and tweak them every time after I run the program to get an optimal result.

In the code below, the values are 6 and 11, 11 respectively.

Given the code below:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('RedJan20.png')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blur
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (0,0), sigmaX=99, sigmaY=99)

# do division normalization
normal = cv2.divide(gray, blur, scale=255)

# stretch to full dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(normal, in_range='image', out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# adaptive threshold  
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 6)

# apply morphology close 
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (11,11))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)

# get external contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]


# filter out small contours and fit ellipse
# draw contour on copy of image and also draw ellipse
result1 = img.copy()
result2 = img.copy()
i = 1
count = 0
for cntr in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cntr)
    #if area > 10000:
    if area > 5000:
        ellipse = cv2.fitEllipse(cntr)
        (xc,yc),(d1,d2),angle = ellipse
        print('ellipse #:', i)
        print('center:', xc,yc)
        print('diameters:', d1,d2)
        print('angle:', angle)
        print('')
        cv2.drawContours(result1, [cntr], 0, (0,0,255), 1)
        cv2.ellipse(result2, (int(xc),int(yc)), (int(d1/2),int(d2/2)), angle, 0, 360, (0,0,255), 1)
        i += 1
        count += 1
print(count)

# show results
cv2.imshow('gray', gray)
cv2.imshow('blur', blur)
cv2.imshow('normalized', normal)
cv2.imshow('stretched', stretch)
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('contours', result1)
cv2.imshow('ellipses', result2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For input image 1 above, having a C value of 6 and morph close value 11, 11 works, but let's say for another [image input 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf2Fg.png), the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQez3.jpg) will not detect all the circles. I have to increase the the C value to 10 and also the morph value to 50, 50 so all the ellipses can be detected.
After changing the values in the code, the output for image 2 looks like this - [output image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/261qF.jpg)

For this other image only when I change the parameters can I obtain desirable results.
[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pwgf5.png) ---> [output3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4qye.jpg)

All in all, for the aforementioned 3 images, these are the values I need for accurate circle detection.

Image 1: **C argument** - 6, **morph values** 11,11
Image 2: **C argument** - 10, **morph values** 50,50
Image 3: **C argument** - 6, **morph values** 50, 50

I want to be able to write an algorithm / script that be able to adjust the values depending on the input image. All the input images I will want to detect will have a constraint of 5 circles only, so what I am thinking is perhaps to start off with a C argument of 6 and morph values 11, 11 first. Then if the output image does not have 5 circles, then the program can increase/decrease the values accordingly until the output has 5 circles.

How should I do this, and is there a better way to approach this problem? Any help will be appreciated! Thank you so much.

Comment: I do not think you can do that with simple 2D image processing. You likely need AI/Deep Learning with training to remove the background. Perhaps some one else can advise better. Have you tried just HoughCircles() on the grayscale image (stretched to full dynamic range).

Comment: I concur. AI. -- those aren't even ellipses. hough transform is bound to fail and so is anything that expects geometrically simple shapes. -- just train some instance segmentation network for this. commonly used networks should have no trouble learning the appearance of these things.